# Mass renaming files that have patern sql_^d^_migration.sql

Tags: rename, file-management

I have the following list of files on an Ubuntu system:

```
sql_1_migration.sql 
sql_2_migration.sql
sql_3_migration.sql
...
sql_100_migration.sql 
sql_1000_migration.sql
...
```

And I need to rename it into:

```
sql_0001_migration.sql 
sql_0002_migration.sql
sql_0003_migration.sql
...
sql_0100_migration.sql 
sql_1000_migration.sql
...
```

Do you know how I can do that in bash? As you can see I want to prepend `0` to the files that have non-4-digit numbers. I need to do it in Ubuntu GNU/Linux OS.

Comment: On what operating system? Does this need to be a bash solution or are you open to other tools like `rename`?

Comment: It is on Ubuntu GNU/Linux. As far as tools I am open as long as I get the appropriate result.

Comment: Is the set of files to rename > 9999 files?

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
rename -n 's/^sql_(\d+)/sprintf "sql_%.04d", $1/e' sql_*_migration.sql
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: The `$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"` shows the following error:
`cannot open \`' (No such file or directory)`

Comment: So: `sudo apt install rename`

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas on Ubuntu, `rename` is this one, `perl-rename` and that will work with Gilles's answer.

Comment: Also the `rename -n 's/^sql_(\d+)/sprintf "%.03d", $1/e' sql_*_migration.sql` shows no output I did `sudo apt install rename` and the `sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename` but shows nothing.

Comment: It's not `udo` but `sudo`. What is the output of `rename -V` ?

Comment: I tried with `sudo` still same result.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas are you running it in a directory that has files that match the `sql_*_migration.sql` glob? If there's no output, there are no matching files. Does `ls sql_*_migration.sql` show any files?

Comment: I needed to `cd` to the path the files being located also the digits should be 4 instead of 3.

Comment: He, hum, koff, yes, POST edited accordingly

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas, you don't need to `cd`, you just need to give `rename` the right files. If they are in your current dir, you can just use `sql_*_migration.sq` but if not, rename won't magically find them, so you can either `cd` to the dir or just use the full or relative path: `/path/to/dir/sql_*_migration.sq`.

Comment: It's not only `rename` behavior but **all** commands lines operating on files on any unix or unix likes